# Load an email (.eml) from desktop to Outlook via Server - Blue Prism

Tags: email, server, outlook

For my project I need to load an email (.eml) from desktop into Outlook so that it remains in that mailbox; everything via Server.

This is because I have to transfer an email from one Outlook mailbox to another one and the only way I thought possible was to download it from a mailbox, save it on the desktop and then reload it on the other box.

I tried to find out an action / code to do that

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. What is your programming language? WHere are you stuck? Can you add more details, you can read [ask] and take the [tour]